# Do I need a new Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in rails 4.1.1 called 'item'

item has several attributes like 'photo1', photo2, etc., which are links to amazon s3 files.

When I edit items, I want to have delete button for each photo in edit item view, which deletes from item instance (link in my db) and s3 file.

I have this working in a crude way but I feel like I am may not doing things ideally.  (I am learning ruby and rails).

Should photo be another model for just s3 photo files?  I created a delphoto method in item controller to which I pass item id and photo choice to delete, but it feels wrong.  Seems like perhaps I should have a photos table that is related model instead.  If it helps, I plan to add other models like fruit, cars, etc that will all have photos too.

Also, should the code to delete be in the controller or the model?  I am guessing model, in which case I would call the model method from item controller to delete right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would definitely make a new model. Have the Item model and then make another model called ItemPhoto with `:item_id` as an attribute to link those rows to their item parent. Then store the photo information in there instead.

I think your questions about delete code will clear up once you move away from having photos in the same model as the item. Delete code should be in the controller.